# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'User'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I developed an API using Django Rest Framework.

I just changed my model in order to link my object to User object of Django by adding **creationUser** and **updateUser** :

```
class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    recipient = models.ForeignKey('Client', models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name='Client')
    provider = models.ForeignKey('Provider', models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name='Provider')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    receptionDate = models.DateField()
    fileName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updateDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    creationUser = models.ForeignKey(User, models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='creationUser') # New Line
    updateUser = models.ForeignKey(User, models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='updateUser') # New Live

    def __str__(self):
        return "Id : {0} | Nom : {1} | Fournisseur : {2} | Type : {3} | Date de reception : {4}".format(self.id, self.name, self.provider, self.type, self.receptionDate)
```

Then I execute :

```
pipenv run python manage.py makemigrations
pipenv run python manage.py migrate
```

First line works, but second line provides :

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, api, auth, contenttypes, inbox, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying api.0027_auto_20180721_0106...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\mjacq\.virtualenvs\gouvernante_is_real-pYxsNaTM\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\mjacq\.virtualenvs\gouvernante_is_real-pYxsNaTM\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 365, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\mjacq\.virtualenvs\gouvernante_is_real-pYxsNaTM\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\mjacq\.virtualenvs\gouvernante_is_real-pYxsNaTM\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 335, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\mjacq\.virtualenvs\gouvernante_is_real-pYxsNaTM\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Users\mjacq\.virtualenvs\gouvernante_is_real-pYxsNaTM\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\mjacq\.virtualenvs\gouvernante_is_real-pYxsNaTM\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\mjacq\.virtualenvs\gouvernante_is_real-pYxsNaTM\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\mjacq\.virtualenvs\gouvernante_is_real-pYxsNaTM\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 122, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\mjacq\.virtualenvs\gouvernante_is_real-pYxsNaTM\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 84, in database_forwards
field,
  File "C:\Users\mjacq\.virtualenvs\gouvernante_is_real-pYxsNaTM\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 407, in add_field
definition, params = self.column_sql(model, field, include_default=True)
  File "C:\Users\mjacq\.virtualenvs\gouvernante_is_real-pYxsNaTM\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 152, in column_sql
default_value = self.effective_default(field)
  File "C:\Users\mjacq\.virtualenvs\gouvernante_is_real-pYxsNaTM\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 224, in effective_default
default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\mjacq\.virtualenvs\gouvernante_is_real-pYxsNaTM\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 936, in get_db_prep_save
return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
  File "C:\Users\mjacq\.virtualenvs\gouvernante_is_real-pYxsNaTM\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 767, in get_db_prep_save
return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "C:\Users\mjacq\.virtualenvs\gouvernante_is_real-pYxsNaTM\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 939, in get_db_prep_value
value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\mjacq\.virtualenvs\gouvernante_is_real-pYxsNaTM\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 947, in get_prep_value
return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'User'
```

I can't understand the Reason. I tried to remove **creationUser** and **updateUser** and run the two commands again but the issue keep happenning.

As requested by Bernard Parah, here is the *api.0027_auto_20180721_0106.py* file :

```
# Generated by Django 2.0.3 on 2018-07-20 23:06

from django.conf import settings
import django.contrib.auth.models
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('api', '0026_case_description'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='document',
            name='creationUser',
            field=models.ForeignKey(default=django.contrib.auth.models.User, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, related_name='creationUser', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='document',
            name='updateUser',
            field=models.ForeignKey(default=django.contrib.auth.models.User, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, related_name='updateUser', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: add the contents of  `api.0027_auto_20180721_0106`. it's in the migration file

Comment: @BernardParah , done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something wrong in your migration file.

```
field=models.ForeignKey(default=django.contrib.auth.models.User, ...
```

There should be no `default` argument there, and `User` is not a proper value for `default` in any case. I don't know what might have happened, since the `default` are not in your Document model. Try removing both `default=django.contrib.auth.models.User,` from the migration file and run `manage.py migrate` again.

You can also try to just delete the migration file and rebuild it with `makemigrations`